# Is there a generic formula to calculate fuel consumption for passenger jets?

Tags: aircraft-performance, flight-planning, fuel

I am working on a game that has to calculate the fuel burn of real life passenger jets. Input values would be roughly the following:

- Route (like JFK-LAX, based on Great Circle Map distance, ideally including reserves, holding, alternates, following real life nav points)
- Estimated flight time
- Aircraft type (A320-200 with Winglets, possibly the MTOW, engine types)
- Possibly the OEW (i.e. cabin configuration/crew/catering)
- Payload (Number of passengers/cargo)

Based on these values I would need a generic formula that can estimate the fuel consumption for such a flight, and/or possibly the max payload in case the range is not enough.

The thing is it should be generic enough so that it's possible to provide the parameters from publicly available information about aircraft types. I am aware of JSBSim or Yasim FDM, although I believe those would be way too detailed and complex for this purpose.

I am not sure if there is something like this as I understand it is quite a complex task.

The current formulas are too simple and do not take into account the payload or other factors, making it too static.

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever look into the Breguet equation? That should do what you want. See [here for example](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8652/how-can-i-calculate-the-fuel-consumption-of-an-airbus-320-200-at-various-loads/8654#8654).

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. I must have overlooked that question when searching here.