# Boeing 757-200 Fuel Burn

Tags: aircraft-performance, takeoff, climb, boeing-757

So up front, I'm aware of the high number of aircraft and environmental factors and how oversimplified my request is. After all, there is a reason that the aircraft manufacturers provide charts to calculate such things, and not hard numbers.

I'm looking for the average fuel burn rates for a Boeing 757-200 at MTOW during the first hour of flight, and then the same, the average fuel burn rate for the second hour of flight. If you have a range for each period, that be cool as well. If you need variables to run the calculation, I offer the following:

- Field Elevation: 1,000' MSL

  - Temp: 59° F/ 15° C Altimeter Setting: 29.92 In-Hg/ QNH 1013 Final
  - Cruising Alt: FL380 Assume standard takeoff configuration and initial climb performance. Standard cruise climb t FL380 with no clearance altitude restrictions or ATC level offs

I think that's it, let me know if I forgot something.

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8652/how-can-i-calculate-the-fuel-consumption-of-an-airbus-320-200-at-various-loads/8654#8654)? Repeat the same for the (rather similar) 757, and you have your numbers. Only the climb phase in the first hour will need special treatment.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I think the B757 burns appreciably more fuel than an A320, in fact I believe it's around 1,000 kg/hr more at MTOW. Still, I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Of course it does, when you look at the absolute numbers. They scale linearly with weight. What you **should**  look at are the relative numbers given in that answer; they should be very similar for the 757.

Comment: Ahhhh, ok, thank you!!